# create directory with node

Tags: files, nodes

I am interested in making a 'physical' folder structure to match a hierarchy I create through content types.

My hierarchy currently exists in the format

```
-Container
--folder
---presentation
```

and I want to create a folder structure when each level is created that mimics this, so that would be

```
[container_name]
[container_name]/[folder_name]
[container_name]/[folder_name]/[presentation_name]
```

I've been trying to use the drupal_mkdir() function within a module of my own creation which uses hook_node_insert, but I am a little too 'green' to know exactly what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method I used to solve this was that in my Drupal site I had entity references at each level that connected me all the way down to my root. It was a simple process of using the functions such as `node_load()` to return information about the entity and its title, which I was then able to concatenate into a string of text like is in the example above: container_name]/[folder_name]/[presentation_name]
After that I was able to simply use this code to build the folder after each node was submitted:

```
//$path contained the remaining file path to be built
$dirpath=variable_get('file_public_path', conf_path() . '/files');
drupal_mkdir("$dirpath/$path");
```